# Is it save to remove old (huge) .git/objects/$folder/$file from loacal laravel application?

Tags: git, laravel-8

Whenever I create a zip package of my laravel application it stalls for perhaps 10 seconds on a particular file in the .git/objects/1c folder

```
-r--r--r-- 1 root root       267 Sep  3 03:51 2594ce9a9da03d6809e24073d6d108825d5742
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 666746290 Sep 15 17:11 3132aadcdf726d34029ea4cfebd0c4be1da404
-r--r--r-- 1 root root      2394 Nov 17 09:36 3b6e5ba61c50d8c98efa06f0e81d9092510aac
```

This = diskspace quite a bit. I would like to know if it will cause any issues with the application or issues when I do a git push if I delete that file?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not safe!

Although it won't affect your Laravel app it will most certainly screw your `git` repository, since [`.git/objects/` is where `git` stores all its contents](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects).
If the contents of `.git/objects/` becomes too large you may want to try [`git gc`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) to garbage collect old files and compress the rest instead.

---

Also if you want to package your files you might want to use [`git archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) instead - unless you want to also package files which are normally ignored by `git`.
Then keep using `zip` but maybe exclude the `.git/` directory which should not be necessary for your application but contains your whole `git` history.

Comment: I've have been learning laravel/git for maybe six months. Made plenty of mistakes, not really sure where this monster came from. Along the way I have done git psh many many times, undoubtedly overkill. Will git gc clean up this file?

Comment: You'll have to try it. `git gc` will aggregate and compress object files to [_pack files_](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles) for more efficiency. When you do a `git push` this is usually done automatically in the background for the new commits. So it may happen that the large file is preserved or may grow even larger. But in that case all its contents are actually needed to preserve **the whole history of your repository locally**.

Comment: to preserve the whole history - let's say that we don't need the history plan to start a new history now that the application is good. Will it be catastrophic to remove that file and the 'past' history?

Comment: Yes, because that file may also contain very recent parts of your history. You should never meddle with the raw objects files directly but use appropriate `git` commands instead! If you want to "compress" your history, look at [squashing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#_squashing). If you want to keep your history but just not _locally_ look at [`git clone --depth`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---depthltdepthgt).

Answer (score 0):

I can't talk to how others manage this stuff but in this particular case the file did not appear to be adding any value while taking a ton of disk space. I went through git log beginning at the beginning of my education and we found that I/we had done about 260 commits. Because much/most of the early stuff was just experiments there was really no need to maintain the history.

We ran a couple experiments.

1. Under the professor's guidance (my mentor) we did a clone and created a demo. This worked perfectly and I checked for any large files and there were none - no 666746290 byte size file. The demo was happy.
2. Not 100% satisfied I created a .zip file minus the big file.

zip -r  --symlinks backups/application.zip vision -x application/storage/app/public* -x application/.env -x application/public/storage -x $fat_file

I ftp the .zip file and database file to another domain and set it up. This worked fine without any hitches.

Normally I concur with whatever folks on the forum say, however sometimes the situation warrants a little interpretation and providing you are comfortable with both filesystem and database backup files, why not experiment.

Either way, thanks.